# Why Restricted Boltzmann Machine(RBM) is better than random initiating?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

To train a Deep neural network, why training Restricted Boltzmann Machine(RBM) layer-wise first and then apply BP algorithm through the network?

Comparing to random initiating all the weights+bias in all layers and then apply BP algorithm, is there a quantitative reason(proof) that pretrained RBM is better than random weights assignment? I found a lot of case(datasets) studies about these two training methods saying RBM is better than random.

(Some documents argued that RBM also could help avoiding local minimizers when running gradient descent, but didn't offer any proof)

Comment: Greedy layer-wise pre-training is not recommended practice, the last I checked. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232616/is-greedy-layer-wise-training-of-deep-networks-necessary-for-successfully-traini

Comment: @Emre thanks! I will take a deep look to that answer. I guess things are changing too fast? As I learned from my professor recently, pre-training is necessary for good initialization weights, but I never figured out why they are "good".

Comment: Welcome to the site and the fast-paced world of machine learning ... [Here's a relevant Quora thread with a response from Bengio](https://www.quora.com/Is-unsupervised-pre-training-and-greedy-layer-wise-pre-training-methods-considered-obsolete-for-modern-deep-learning-Why-or-why-not).

Comment: @Emre thank you, they are really helpful material :=)